# echo ou print, qual realmente é a melhor opção?

Tags: php

Sei das diferenças do echo ou print, mas em um projeto real em PHP qual é o mais indicado a se usar? Ou simplesmente tanto faz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um é *praticamente* apelido para o outro.

O `print` também existe em C, linguagem do qual o PHP se baseou fortemente, logo alguns livros ou cursos inicias de PHP, ou mesmo professores mais acostumados com C, podem usar `print`. Porém em geral como outros programadores PHP não iniciantes usam `echo`, **então tende a ser interessante usar o echo fora da faculdade**.

Ainda que o `print` exiba exemplos como `print("Alô Mundo")`, não é necessário por eles. Creio que a única diferença *útil* que o `print` poderia ter em relação ao `echo` é que ele retorna `1`, porém se pretende deixar que outras pessoas deem manutenção no seu código, não tem real necessidade de explorar isso.

Veja [documentação do echo em php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php) e a [documentação no print php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print.php).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Emerson.

Answer (score 10):

Depende da necessiade, tanto `echo` quanto `print` são  [language constructs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) a diferença entre eles é que `print` sempre retorna `1`(true) já o `echo` não retorna nada.

**print**

```
echo print('ola mundo');
```

A saida será `ola mundo1`. O print ainda pode ser usado com ternarios enquanto o `echo` não.

```
$p = ($idade <10) ? print ('menor') : print('maior'); //valido

$p = ($idade <10) ? echo ('menor') : echo ('maior'); //invalido,
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO
```

Comment: A vantagem que eu vejo nisso é em expressões do tipo `<?php isset($value) and print($value) ?>`, que com o `echo` não tem como fazer.

Comment: Nesse caso creio que também pode ser digitado com `echo` usando operador ternário: `<?php echo isset($value) ? $value : ''; ?>`.

Answer (score 8):

São praticamente idênticos.

O `print` tem o detalhe de retornar um valor, 1 no caso de ter corrido. Assim pode usar-se

```
$printou = print('foo');
```

O `echo` permite concatenar variáveis/strings:

```
echo 'Olá!', ' mundo', '!'; // dá "Olá mundo!"
echo 'Olá!'.' mundo'.'!'; // dá "Olá mundo!"
```

O `echo` tem ainda a vantagem de ter um atalho quando se escreve misturado em html:

```
<?=$minhaVariavel?>
```

Comment: Obrigado por comentar Sergio. 
Mas essa forma de atalho <?=$var?> não tem riscos futuros? Claro desde que o servidor esteja configurado devido ao <?php ...

Comment: @phpricardo, pode ter, uma boa imagem (em Inglês) sobre isso: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgkl8.png , __[deste post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)__.

Comment: Mas concatenar variáveis e strings o print também faz

Answer (score 3):

A melhor opção é `echo` porque economizará um byte no tamanho do arquivo do seu código-fonte, a cada vez que for preferida no lugar de `print` (pois `echo` tem 4 caracteres e `print` tem 5 caracteres).

A melhor opção será `print` apenas se você precisar usar a expressão num ternário ou receber um valor de retorno.

Comment: Além do mais, `echo` nos remete ao [alien `Echo Echo` do Ben 10](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_gYByhIgkwB4/TExH3a3GfhI/AAAAAAAAA8U/VMJdTmCU1Vo/s1600/echo-echo.png), enquanto `print` não nos faz lembrar de alien nenhum!

Comment: Por que vale a pena economizar bytes no fonte em php?

Comment: Por que desperdiçar bytes no fonte em php?

Answer (score 2):

É melhor usar o `echo`.

Principalmente, porque echo aceita múltiplos  parâmetros; já o `print` não.

Que, no caso, geraria uma diferença considerável na hora de imprimir a instrução abaixo

```
echo  'Olá ', 'Meu nome é Wallace',
      ' e Eu tenho ', 30  - 6 , ' anos de idade', PHP_EOL;
      //Olá Meu nome é Wallace e Eu tenho 24 anos de idade

echo  'Olá ' . 'Meu nome é Wallace' .
      ' e Eu tenho ' . 30  -  6 . ' anos de idade'; // -6 anos de idade
```

Em relação ao print, a única vantagem que vejo em usá-lo ao invés do `echo` seria para simplificar uma expressão condicional para imprimir um valor.

Exemplos:

```
//Com `print`:

<?php isset($value) && print($value) ?>

//Com `echo` PHP 5.3 ou anteriores 

<?php echo isset($value) ? $value : null; ?>

//No PHP 5.4+ já podemos fazer isso sem precisar habilitar o short_tags

<?= isset($value) ? $value : null; ?>
```

Mas essa é uma diferença bem pequena!

Comment: Eu ia responder sobre as virgulas, mas vi tua resposta, então +1