# Como utilizar o echo e o print em php

Tags: php

Galera eu estou iniciando no mundo do php e gostaria de saber a diferença e, em que mais se adequa a utilização dos comandos: echo, print () echo "". A sim e também saber a diferença em utilizar as aspas simples e duplas '' e "".

Comment: Sobre as aspas, já está respondido aqui: [Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/) - Use sempre as simples, se não precisar de substituição de variáveis.

Comment: Sobre echo e print, já está respondido aqui: [echo ou print, qual realmente é a melhor opção?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4943/)